# JAVA: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I am trying to determine the Hamming distance between two arrays of ints. Pre: aList != null, bList != null, aList.length == bList.length; Post: return the Hamming Distance between the two arrays of ints. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am just now starting to learn how to code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Here is my code:

```
public class test {

public static int hammingDistance(int[] aList, int[] bList) {
    // check preconditions
    if (aList == null || bList == null || aList.length != bList.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Violation of precondition: " +
            "hammingDistance. neither parameter may equal null, arrays" +
            " must be equal length.");
    //Starting a counter
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("test");
    //checking to see if there is a mismatch in the values of the two given arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < bList.length; i++) {
        if (bList[i] != aList[i]) {
            //increasing counter everytime there is a mismatch
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] aList = { 1,3,3,4 };
    int[] bList = { 1,2,10,4 };
    System.out.println(hammingDistance(aList, bList));
}
```

}

*Updated Code*

Comment: Get rid of “else { counter = 0; }”

Comment: I got rid of it and ran the code and nothing is printing.

Comment: "nothing is printing" -> program is not running (to the end) (BTW: not necessary to create a `new test` - not being used)

Comment: Removed the `new test` and pasted updated code.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting the counter to zero whenever there is a match. So counter in never effective. Remove the else part of the code.

Comment: Oh thats right! I made that change. However, when I run the code, nothing is printing on my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the `counter` when two elements are equal (see your `else` statement). You shouldn't be doing anything when two called are equal.

Hope it helps,